# An Agreement, In/Under Which

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions, usage

I have a question about the usage of the prepositions "*in*" and "*under*".  Suppose the context is John giving $1000 to Jane as part of some agreement:

> 1. They signed an agreement ***in*** which John gave Jane $1000.
> 2. They signed an agreement ***under*** which John gave Jane $1000.

Both versions using "*in*" and "*under*" are likely standard English found in newspaper articles, and in general probably loosely mean the same thing to most people.  But is there any minor differences in meaning between "*in*" and "*under*"?

Answer (score 1):

You can be *in* or *under* an agreement, so both are valid.  *Under* has an implication that it's a written or legal agreement (similar to something being "under contract").

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about something that has been signed we are talking about a legal document. The agreement will contain details of what John has promised to do. If we use precise terminology the agreement will have **in** it the details of the promise.

> They signed an agreement in which John undertook  to give Jane $1000.

The actual action of giving was under the terms of the agreement, the agreement determined John's behaviour

> They signed an agreement under which John gave Jane $1000.

So if we talk about the actual content of the agreement then use **in** and if we talk about the resulting actions use "under".

If on the other hand we are simply talking about an agreement between two people, not signing anything

> Their agreement was that John should give Jane $500.
>
> They were in agreement that ...